# Execute a cron job from a method using python in odoo 12

Tags: python, xml, odoo-12

I'd like to execute a Cron Job at the end of the method execution when I click a button, I read [this post](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/call-cron-job-manually-with-button-168207) which mention to explicitly run a method, but it isn't working for me.

So far this is what I got:

my cron job

```
 <record id="ir_cron_save_timesheets" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Save timesheets</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="rw_project.model_rw_file_reader"/>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">model.process_ts()</field>
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">days</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
        </record>
```

in the button code at the end I want to execute this:

```
self.env.ref('project_name.ir_cron_save_timesheets').process_ts()
```

In the model, I do have a method name called process_ts

the error that I'm getting is:

> AttributeError: 'ir.cron' object has no attribute 'process_ts'

If I remove process_ts it doesn't get executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call `process_ts` on a cron record which is wrong, the `process_ts` method is defined in the `rw_project.model_rw_file_reader` model.

You have just to call the `method_direct_trigger()` and it should call the `process_ts()` method:

```
self.env.ref('project_name.ir_cron_save_timesheets').method_direct_trigger()
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly, is there a way to make the call asyncronous, that executes in the background, so far the call it's executing in the button method context

Comment: If you do not want to block UI, you can use a thread as Odoo does for cron jobs. You can see also `_process_jobs` and `_process_job` in `ir_cron.py` which create a new connection and environment before running the cron function.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, It does not seem interesting to trigger a cron from python, because - as Kenly said previouly - the UI remains spining, waiting for the cron-process to get completed ... because it does not run in another thread. and a pythonic solution is still missing.

The best and easiest way to get an asynchronous job in Odoo, would be to call your method process_ts() using a button related to an ajax/rpc (+Promise) in javascript.